# JS - typeof doesn't work with input | document.getElementById issue

Tags: javascript, document, getelementbyid, typeof, let

I need to ask for help in solving two issues.

1. `document.getElementById.value` saved in `let` doesn't work with `innerHTML` saved in a different `let`. I saw a few similar threads, but they haven't helped me out.
2. An issue appears when I need to check the number by `typeof`, it just runs as JS doesn't see it.

Here is my code. Thanks for any advice and help.

```js
function wage() {
    let input = document.getElementById('annualInput').value;
    let output = document.getElementById('resultMonthly').innerHTML;
    
    // it doesn't work, but it works with pure document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = input;
    output = input;
 
    /*  
        if (input !== '') {
            // this if doesn't work even with string and number
            if (typeof input == 'number')
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = input;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Please, type your annual wage';
        }
    */

    // annual wage devided by 12 months
    let resultMonthly = input / 12;
    let showMonthly = 'Your monthly wage: ' + resultMonthly.toFixed(2);
    
    // monthly wage devided by 20 days
    let resultDaily = resultMonthly / 20;
    let showDaily = 'Your daily wage: ' + resultDaily.toFixed(2);
    
    // daily wage devided by 8 hours
    let resultHourly = resultDaily / 8;
    let showHourly = 'Your hourly wage: ' + resultHourly.toFixed(2);
    
    if (input !== '') {
        document.getElementById('resultMonthly').innerHTML = showMonthly + ' $';
        document.getElementById('resultDaily').innerHTML = showDaily + ' $';
        document.getElementById('resultHourly').innerHTML = showHourly + ' $';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('resultMonthly').innerHTML = 'Please, type your annual wage';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wage App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Issue App</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wageup.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">            
            <!-- the title and desc -->
            <h1 class="display-4 text-center">WageApp</h1>
            <p class="h6 text-center" id="paragraphTitle">
                This is a simple App for calculating wage by year, month, day and hour
            </p>
            <hr class="my-4">

            <!-- input-form -->
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="annualInput">Your annual wage</label>
                    <input type="annualData" class="form-control" id="annualInput" aria-describedby="hep" placeholder="Annual wage in $">
                    <small id="help" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your wage with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
                <button onclick="wage()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="checkButton">Check</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="resultMonthly"></div>
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="resultDaily"></div>
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" id="resultHourly"></div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="wageUp.js">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `type="annualData"`? and the type of a textbox is going to be a string, it is not going to be a number.

Comment: the value of a normal input element is of type string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

```
output = input;
```

This doesn't work because `output` is not referencing the element, it is storing the innerHTML of that element.

**Solving Issue 1:**

Your comment is a good place to start:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = input;
```

Or, you can store the element to a variable and then set the innerHTML:

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
// later on
result.innerHTML = input;
```

---

**Issue 2:**

```
if (typeof input == 'number')
```

This will never be true because values stored in the value attribute of an element are always string.

**Solving Issue 2:**

You can check in numerous ways if the input is a string version of a number, one such way is testing if the string is not NaN:

```
if (!isNaN(input))
```

Since there are so many ways to do this check, I'd look around to find the one that seems appropriate for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I have one question to your Solving Issue 2. I changed the if to yours if (!isNaN(input)), but it still accepts strings. How can I change this: if (typeof input == 'number') to accept only numbers?

Comment: Use `input = +input` to transform the string into a number. If he can't, it'll be `NaN`

Comment: @Adam, it depends, can users use commas (ex: `1,234.12`)? Because if they can, don't attempt coercion (`+'1,234'` is NaN).

Comment: @Kulvar the problem is that I don't want the `NaN`, but the last part of if code to run, namely `else {
        document.getElementById('resultMonthly').innerHTML = 'Please, type your annual wage';
    }`
@KevBot let's suppose they can't use commas in the early stage

Comment: If the user type "one thousands two hundred thirty four dollars and twelve cents", you'll have a NaN. If he type "1234.12" you'll have a float number. As for thousand separator, you can replace invalid characters. `input = +(input.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""))`

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` and `value` are a "magic" property with a getter and a setter. You can't get a direct reference to them. You can either store the current value that'll not be updated, or you can however store the node to use their magic properties.

Input values are always strings. You must cast it as a number using unary operator `+` and then test the result with `Number.isNaN()`.